Corruption in config_default for Concurrent Jobs with gcloud
I am concurrently running some scripts that utilize gcloud commands (auth activate-service-account and config set) and have noticed the config_default file occasionally getting corrupted with parts of the project or service account being appended to the end of that file, thus making it an invalid config file to read from.
In my environment/host, I have multiple Linux users, which I associate one (or more) Google service accounts to. For cases where it is a one-to-one mapping of Linux user to Google service account, I have ruled out using multiple configurations. I use these gcloud setup commands at the start of each script to ensure the user is using the intended project and service account.
Has anyone also encountered this type of corruption issue before? I suspect the issue is running these gcloud commands concurrently. Also, what are some best practices to follow for dealing with multiple service accounts across different users in a single (Linux) host?
I noticed that in Google docs for gcloud scripting:

Note: Parallel execution of multiple gcloud CLI commands is not supported.

I tried to get around this by using flock to lock the config_default file if I know there are multiple concurrently running scripts, but this approach may not be practical if I have long running jobs (unless I send them to the background with &).
